# Render Critical CSS inline within header C# @Styles.Render

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to inject CSS into the head of a website so that it is inline.

I have my CSS file bundled up and minified as below

```
    BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css").Include(
        "~/css/stylesheet.css"
    ));
```

I then add it to my master template like below

```
    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/css")
```

Which then links out to a CSS file. But what i would like to do is render it inline within the header so i can reduce my initial load times and help eliminate render blocking CSS.

Comment: If you want to speed up load times, then host the css on a different server (then your HTML and CSS will be loaded in parallel).   Also, don't have  MASSIVE css file, and simplify your page so that it doesn't make 100s of requests at load time.

Comment: Thanks for the information, One of the many tasks im working on is to reduce the amount of requests, although this isnt removing a request, it will delay the request which will help also. See https://web.dev/render-blocking-resources/#how-to-eliminate-render-blocking-stylesheets for more info

Comment: I think you're talking about Critical [Path] CSS. (?) IIRC, you have to do that kind of css by hand. The point of using it is so you don't make a request or use any code, it's just already there on the page.